# ¿Cómo destaco una barra en GGPLOT2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Tengo el siguiente d.f

```
estados<- data.frame("estado"=c("AGS", "CDMX", "MEX"), "pib"=c(1,2,3))
```

Mi código para hacer la gráfica es el siguiente

```
ggplot(estados, aes(x=reorder(estado,-pib), y=pib))+labs(x="Estado", y= "%", caption = "Fuente: Elaboración propia ")+ geom_bar(fill="blue4", stat = "identity")+theme(axis.text.x = element_text(color="black",size=8, angle=90))+scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0,2,4), limits = c(0,5))
```

Sin embargo, quisiera destacar de otro color la barra "CDMX" para hacer un énfasis especial.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero me puedan ayudar, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sólo tienes que cambiar el color en el argumento `fill` del geom_bar.

```
ggplot(estados, aes(x=reorder(estado,-pib), y=pib))+
  labs(x="Estado", y= "%", caption = "Fuente: Elaboración propia ")+
  geom_bar(fill=c("blue4","red","blue4"), stat = "identity")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(color="black",size=8, angle=90))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0,2,4), limits = c(0,5))
```

Estoy colocando en la barra del medio el color rojo.

```
geom_bar(fill=c("blue4","red","blue4"), stat = "identity")
```

Que te queda de la siguiente manera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias. En caso de tener un grupo mayor de barras, ¿Sería el mismo procedimiento? Gracias

Comment: Sí, sólo colocar el mismo número de colores con el número de barras.